Fundamental Group of a Surface of genus $g$ can be realized as a deck transformation of isometries on its universal cover.
If $\Sigma_g$ is a closed surface of genus $g\ge2$, then there exists a deck transformation of isometries on its universal cover $\mathbb H^2$ isomorphic to $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$.
I’m comfortable with the covering space theory involved with there being a deck transformation on $\mathbb H^2$ whose quotient is $\Sigma_g$, but why can the deck transformation on be chosen to be given completely by the action of isometries? Is this due to the fact that $g\ge2$ so the Euler characteristic is less than $0$ so the surface can be given a hyperbolic metric?
Any insight would be appreciated.

Yes, use the existence theorem for hyperbolic metrics and the fact that universal cover with the pull back metric is isometric to the hyperbolic plane.
